# Extracting Date and time data from Cell to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with a column which contains date in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd h:mm

I want to store the date and time in two separate VBA string variables.  How would I go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried doing any research? Is the cell storing the date as a serial date? If it is you can just extract the value2 from the cell. It will be a long data type value. The integer part represents the date and the fractions the time. You can research more about this searching for Excel serial date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Split** function to extract the date and the time in two differents variables.

```
Dim aDate() As String
Dim separatedDate As String
Dim separatedTime As String

'Put the value before the " " (space character) in the first case of the array 
'and the value after the " " (space character) in the second case
aDate = Split(Range("Cell where you date is").Value, " ", -1)

'You can now access these values and store them in variables
separatedDate = aDate(0)
separatedTime = aDate(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the values as **Strings**:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    ary = Split(Range("A1").Text, " ")
    DateAsString = ary(0)
    TimeAsString = ary(1)
End Sub
```